# Asp.net MVC EF SQL Server returns int -1 and not Objectresult radius search

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am working at a Application which shows the visitor locations in a given radius.
So I made a stored Procedure to let the sqlserver the work:
´

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GEO_Get_Events_Map_Time](
@RADIUS INT,
@LAT VARCHAR(10),
@LONG VARCHAR(10))

AS
BEGIN        
declare @GEO1 GEOGRAPHY=null
SET @geo1= geography::Point(@LAT, @LONG, 4326)        

  SELECT tbl_Address.ID,street,
         LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
         (@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(LAT,0),ISNULL(LONG,0), 
          4326)))/1000),5)+' Km' as DISTANCE,
                creator,
                StartTime
  FROM  tbl_address join tbl_Event on tbl_address.ID = tbl_event.id
  WHERE (@GEO1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(LAT,0),ISNULL(LONG,0), 4326)))/1000 < @RADIUS and StartTime > GETDATE()
 END
 GO
```

I updated the model and when I Call the Stored Procedure it returns an integer with value: -1 Here:

```
            using (var  cont = new LazyWebEntities())
           {
               var a = cont.sp_GEO_Get_Events_Map_Time(10, "48.210033", "16.363449");
               Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
              Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

in Model.Context.cs it generates:

```
        public virtual int sp_GEO_Get_Events_Map_TimeNEW(Nullable<int> rADIUS, string lAT, string lONG)
    {
        var rADIUSParameter = rADIUS.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("RADIUS", rADIUS) :
            new ObjectParameter("RADIUS", typeof(int));

        var lATParameter = lAT != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("LAT", lAT) :
            new ObjectParameter("LAT", typeof(string));

        var lONGParameter = lONG != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("LONG", lONG) :
            new ObjectParameter("LONG", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_GEO_Get_Events_Map_TimeNEW", rADIUSParameter, lATParameter, lONGParameter);
    }
```

whats really strange because when I let run the SP at the SQLServer it returns
the data like requestet

I hope you can help me.
Thank you for your answers
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Hy Guys. Here ist the answer to my own question. I tryed a lot of different ways. Bitte nothing worked. So a friend of mine had the idea:
I Made a query  without geographie Type, stored it in the DB andere updated the edmx. Then I altered the Stored Procedere (Look at the Pictures). Now IT worked. If Somebody has the same Problem leave a comment. I will give you further Infos.